# Android movement after swipe

Tags: android, touch

I'm writing component which tracks user's swipe on it.
I can create `onTouch` listener, I'm getting all events.
It would work fine if I wanted only track single movements.

I want to achieve "moving object" effect. So if user touched screen and moved his finger 20 units to right in 2 seconds I don't want to get single 20 units right movements, but I want this movement to continue, slowing down. So in the next 2 seconds I'd like to get another, lets say, 10 units movement.

User additional should be able to stop this movement, i.e. by touching my component again.

I know, there is many "number pickers" having similar behavior. User can swipe through such picker and numbers are starting to change as fast as user swiped, and then slower and slower.
The problem with such pickers are that I cannot extract easily just this behavior and their are pretty complex.

Where should I start? Is there anything done or should I write everything myself?

My only idea was to create some timer for such component. User touches would change speed (start/stop movement and change velocity) and timer would calculate movement and decrease speed (taking elapsed time into the account).

If this is correct solution, how such timer should be create for android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give a more concrete answer if I see some of your code; specifically, what "moving 20 units" looks like in code. That said you can use a GestureDetector to intercept scroll and fling events.

In your view that you want to be "swipeable", add code like the following:

```
if (mGestureListener == null) {
    mGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener();
}
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, mGestureListener);
mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
this.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
```

Then, in your Activity, create a class which extends `SimpleOnGestureListener`. In that class, override the onFling and onScroll methods -- again, I can't really tell you what to put in there without seeing your code. But these callbacks receive the information that you'd need to create your methods: the MotionEvent which started the gesture, the MotionEvent which finished it, and the x & y velocity for fling or the x & y distance for scroll.

If you want it to move a certain distance and then slow down, you can add a `ValueAnimator` on whatever property causes the movement and give it a `DecelerateInterpolator`.

Finally, when you set up your activity, pass your view a new instance of your gesture listener class and use it to set mGestureListener in your swipeable view.